# Grand total of Columns using Sum (if) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I am trying to calculate the grand total of columns I just created with a SUM (if). I have a table with several product numbers but I want to get totals for specific products only. This is my query:

```
Select date(orders.OrderDate) As Date,
Sum(If((orders.ProductNumber = '1'), orders.Qty, 0)) As `Product 1`,
Sum(If((orders.ProductNumber = '2'), orders.Qty, 0)) As `Product 2`,
Sum(If((orders.ProductNumber = '3'), orders.Qty, 0)) As `Product 3`,
From orders
Group By date(orders.OrderDate)
```

I get the totals for each product in columns as expected, but when I try to get the grand total `(Product 1 + product 2 + Product 3)` using `Sum(orders.Qty) as Total`, I get the SUM of ALL products in the table and not only the 3 I am looking for.

How can I get the `SUM(Product 1 + Product 2 + Product 3)`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(o.OrderDate) AS date,
       SUM(IF(o.ProductNumber = '1', o.Qty, 0)) AS `Product 1`,
       SUM(IF(o.ProductNumber = '2', o.Qty, 0)) AS `Product 2`,
       SUM(IF(o.ProductNumber = '3', o.Qty, 0)) AS `Product 3`, 
       SUM(IF(o.ProductNumber IN ('1', '2', '3'), o.Qty, 0)) AS `Total`
FROM orders o
GROUP BY DATE(o.OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pre-cutting rows other than 1, 2, 3. This is faster when `ProductNumber` is INDEXed column.

```
SELECT DATE(orders.OrderDate) AS Date,
    SUM(IF((orders.ProductNumber = '1'), orders.Qty, 0)) AS `Product 1`,
    SUM(IF((orders.ProductNumber = '2'), orders.Qty, 0)) AS `Product 2`,
    SUM(IF((orders.ProductNumber = '3'), orders.Qty, 0)) AS `Product 3`,
    SUM(orders.Qty) AS Total
FROM orders
WHERE
    orders.ProductNumber IN ('1', '2', '3')
GROUP BY DATE(orders.OrderDate)
```